# Magento2: what is the difference between layout and page_layout?

Tags: magento2

As I dig deeper in Magento 2, I noticed that there are layout and page_layout file? What are the differences between the two?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well if i put this in simple words than

**page_layout** represents the full page, i mean you can declare your own full page without inheriting any master or root or other empty layout. (only use, if you want to completely customize your own full page.)

**layout** represents the part of the page (mostly the html content).  You can use this when you want your page to inherit the common contents from the root layout like header, footer etc etc.

Answer (score 4):

**Layout XML** is a tool to build the pages of the Magento application in a modular and flexible manner. It enables us to describe the page layout and content placement.

Looking at XML root nodes, we differentiate two types of layouts:

```
1. layout: XML wrapped in <layout>
2. page: XML wrapped in <page>
```

**Page** layouts represent a full page in HTML, whereas **layout** layouts represent a part of a page.

The **layout** type is a subset of the **page layout** type. Both types of layout XML files are validated by the XSD schema found under the ***vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/etc/*** directory:

```
1. layout – layout_generic.xsd
2. page – page_configuration.xsd
```

Based on the application components that provide  and  elements, we can further section them as **base** and **theme layouts**.

The **base layouts** are provided by the modules, usually at the following locations:

```
1. <module_dir>/view/frontend/layout: page configuration and generic layout files
2. <module_dir>/view/frontend/page_layout: page layout files
```

The **theme layouts** are provided by the themes, usually at the following locations:

```
1. <theme_dir>/<Namespace>_<Module>/layout: page configuration and generic
layout files
2. <theme_dir>/<Namespace>_<Module>/page_layout: page layout files
```

Magento will load and merge all module and theme XML files on the appropriate page.

Once files are merged and XML instructions are processed, the result is rendered and sent
to the browser for display.

Answer (score 2):

**Page layout** declares the wireframe of a page inside the  section, for example one-column layout or two-column layout.

Allowed layout instructions:

```
 <container>
 <referenceContainer>
 <move>
 <update>
```

**Generic layouts** define the contents and detailed structure inside the `<body>` section of the HTML page markup.

Conventionally generic layout files must be located as follows:

```
Module generic layouts: <module_dir>/view/frontend/layout
Theme generic layouts: <theme_dir>/<Namespace>_<Module>/layout
```

Follow this link for overview of layout overview: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-overview.html

And some more detailed information about the layout file types: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-types.html