# Magento2: How can get current page layout?

Tags: magento2.3, layout

How can I get the current page layout programatically?

I have tried this:

```
$block->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getPageLayout();
```

But the output is: `1column` but that is wrong.

Any idea how to get it?

Comment: try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/273974/36463

Comment: What your question? First, please understand different between layout and page_layout?https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/210851/magento2-what-is-the-difference-between-layout-and-page-layout

Comment: i have selected an page_layout in the backend for my group product, and i want to check programmatically what page_layout was selected

Answer (score 0):

> Add this code in your file where you want to get.

```
protected $request;

public function __construct(
    ............................................
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
    ............................................
){
    ............................................
    $this->request = $request;
    ............................................
}
```

> Now you can add this code in your custom function or execute() function

```
    $controller = $this->request->getControllerName();
    $action     = $this->request->getActionName();
    $route      = $this->request->getRouteName();

    echo $controller."<br/>";
    echo $action."<br/>";
    echo $route."<br/>";
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***